# ArrayList Not Working With File Input

Tags: java, file, input, jlabel

I have this program working without the input from files, I have tried lots of googling and asking, but cannot figure it out. I had to change `firstnames` and `secondnames` to an ArrayList, any ideas how to fix this? It also works with all the input from files commented out.

```
package com.gamenamegenerator;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class GameNameGenerator{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException{    
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game Name Generator");
        frame.setSize(1400, 1200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground( Color.black );
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 75));
        label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        ArrayList<String> firstnames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> secondnames = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] firstnameslist = new String[] {"Healthy", "Closed", "Open", "Central", "Remorseful", "Sideways", "Diving", "Trackable", "Wary", "Determined", "Contested", "Continuous", "Hungry", "Limited", "Accredited", "Junky", "Hilarious", "Real", "Stiff", "Agile", "Solid", "Knowing", "Expectant", "Heavy", "Dense", "Unexpectant", "Insolent", "Accurate", "Sufferable", "Painful", "Wise", "Knowledgeable", "Growing", "Confused", "Careful", "Untrusting", "Untrustworthy", "Trusting", "Trustworthy", "Laughing", "Sick", "Hasty", "Reluctant", "Barbaric", "Desperate", "Returning", "Mechanical", "Pondering", "Thoughtful", "Dark", "Positive", "Hated", "Spiteful", "Hateful", "Shimmering", "Assumptive", "Brainy", "Battling", "Commercial", "Bankrupt", "Back Firing", "Babysitting", "Pampered", "Pocket", "Adaptive", "Wet", "Automatic", "Shaky", "Sorrowful", "Experienced", "Inexperienced", "Smooth", "Youthful", "Technological", "Advanced", "Minor", "Hungry", "Misguided", "Feverish", "Drunk", "Dependent", "Burnt", "Humiliated", "Bossy", "Peaceful", "Official", "Junior", "Logical", "Absent", "Curious", "Sharp", "Black", "Broad", "Flabby", "Runny", "Cold Hearted", "Cold", "Fiery", "Speeding", "Flying", "Awoken", "Camoflaged", "Iron", "Golden", "Watchful", "Guarding", "Avenging", "Displaced", "Broken", "Mismatched", "Glistening", "Turbulent", "Difficult", "Approving", "Floating", "Aquatic", "Energetic", "Vibrant", "Animated", "Metallic", "Streamlined", "Cracked", "Aerobatic", "Flimsy", "Absurd", "Dozing", "Dopy", "Pointy", "Paranormal", "Angry", "Slurping", "Gasping", "Oblivious", "Babbling", "Steroid Taking", "Steroids", "Mutated", "Chubby", "Uncooperative", "Smelly", "Inhuman", "Accidental", "Freak", "Scientific", "Combative", "Inaccessible", "Abusive", "Extraterrestrial", "Extravagant", "Undeniably", "Combat", "Enormous", "Giant", "Overrated", "Undeniable", "Secretive", "Comprehensive", "Legendary", "Treacherous", "Deceptive", "Lying", "Hairy", "Loony", "Skinny", "Scrawny", "Genetically Modified", "Modified", "Super", "Arrogant", "Mysterious", "Sneaky", "Deadly", "Fatal", "Dangerous", "Breezy", "Superior", "Flabbergasted", "Mouldy", "Molten", "Squishy", "Moist", "Mushy", "Fluffy", "Magical", "Slimy", "Sloppy", "Elderly", "Stout", "Fat", "Genetically Mutated", "Mutated", "Space", "Cheeky", "Violent", "Amputated", "Snowy", "Poisonous", "Stale", "Alpine", "Rural", "Urban", "Sparkling", "Epicer", "Clumsy", "Interactive", "Edible", "Sublime", "Woollen", "Toxic", "Flammable", "Lazy", "Glowing", "Explosive", "Exploring", "Colossal", "United", "Water", "Clever", "Irresistible", "Grumpy", "Ballistic", "Rebellious", "Majestic"};
        String[] secondnameslist = new String[] {"Life", "Warmonger", "Computer", "Buttocks", "Drink", "Aid", "Shot", "Mate", "Standards", "Alien", "Cloud", "Trees", "Nursing", "Time Bomb", "Bomb", "Time", "Times", "Happiness", "Gunfire", "Heart", "Darkness", "Positivity", "Hater", "Oil", "Spy", "Outsider", "Insider", "Biscuit", "Business", "Advertisement", "Instrument", "Balaclava", "Backpacker", "Back Fire", "Believer", "Handler", "Weakling", "Man", "Peacock", "Buddy", "Revenge", "Eye", "Bear", "Bin", "Nose", "Rocket", "Golem", "Guard", "Sentry", "Canine", "Bone", "Error", "Robot", "Rock", "Stick", "Invention", "Bear", "Koala", "Dinosaur", "Bunny", "Bubble", "Chocolate", "Creation", "Accident", "Mutation", "Mongoose", "Vibrations", "Liar", "Merchant", "Orb", "Turnip", "Wombat", "Creature", "Strength", "Contempt", "Disk", "Vegetable", "Vegan", "Squirrel ", "Mud", "Cheese", "Tape", "Lava", "Magma", "Rainbow", "Devil", "Dwarf", "Remix", "Sapling", "Owl", "Poison", "Butterfly", "Flatulence", "Flop", "Fail", "Fart", "Cake", "Monkey", "Penguin", "Dog", "Cat", "Block", "Steam", "Goose", "Waste", "Nightmare", "Potato", "Nerd", "Cookie", "Whale", "Falcon", "Chipmunk", "Carrot", "Donkey", "Toad", "Cauliflower", "Fire", "Gust", "Bumfluff", "Blob", "Puppy", "Cube", "Butt Cheeks", "Bumfluffles"};
        for(int i = 0; i < firstnameslist.length; i++){
            firstnames.add(firstnameslist[i]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < secondnameslist.length; i++){
            firstnames.add(secondnameslist[i]);
        }
        Scanner firstnameinput = null;
        try{
            firstnameinput = new Scanner(new File("firstnameinput.txt"));
            firstnameinput.useDelimiter(", ");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("File firstnameinput.txt not found! :(");
        }
        while(firstnameinput.hasNext()){
            String a = firstnameinput.next();
            System.out.print(a + " ");

            firstnames.add(a);
        }
        firstnameinput.close();
        Scanner secondnameinput = null;
        try{
            secondnameinput = new Scanner(new File("secondnameinput.txt"));
            secondnameinput.useDelimiter(", ");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("File secondnameinput.txt not found! :(");
        }
        while(secondnameinput.hasNext()){
            String a = secondnameinput.next();
            System.out.print(a + " ");

            secondnames.add(a);
        }
        secondnameinput.close();
        while(true){
            Random rnd = new Random();

            int n1 = rnd.nextInt(firstnames.size() - 1);
            int n2 = rnd.nextInt(secondnames.size() - 1);

            int combinations = firstnames.size() * secondnames.size();

            String result = firstnames.get(n1) +  " " + secondnames.get(n2);
            System.out.println(result);

            label.setText(result);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            frame.add(label);
            try {
                File file = new File("generatednames.txt");
                FileWriter x = new FileWriter(file, true);
                x.write(result + ", ");
                x.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Could not open or create text file!");
            }
            try{
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("gamenamegeneratorstats.txt", "UTF-8");
                writer.println("STATS FOR THIS VERSION");
                writer.println("Possible Combinations: " + combinations);
                writer.println("Please enjoy your generated names!");
                writer.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println("Could not open or create text file!");
            }
            Thread.sleep(2500);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So much to correct here, too much in fact and so I urge you to: 1. Start over. 2. Follow basic Java and OOPs principles from the beginning, including creating multiple classes, some that deal with the state and logic of your program and others that deal with the GUI. 3. Get most of your code out of the static main method and into the instance world where it belongs (see #2 about following OOPs principles for more on this). 4. Respect Swing threading (your code doesn't with its `while (true)` loop and `Thread.sleep(...)`).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok, thanks for the advice, as you can obviously see I am very new to programming and especially java. Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code still a few problems.
The main issue you need to learn is [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) ( All other Swing component methods must be invoked from the event dispatch thread)

You need update your code:

```
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setResizable(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

with calling within SwingUtilities

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
});
```

And change:

```
    label.setText(result);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    frame.add(label);
```

to

```
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        label.setText(result);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    });
```

Comment: Still no luck even with your changes

Comment: It is still just a black screen.

Comment: Any exception you see?

Comment: Yes there is this Exception in thread "main" File firstnameinput.txt not found! :(
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.gamenamegenerator.GameNameGenerator.main(GameNameGenerator.java:52) but when I exported it and had that file it still didnt work.

Comment: That is reason i told "a few problems" and you need to fix it first

Comment: with the files in there this error appears Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
 at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)
 at com.gamenamegenerator.GameNameGenerator.main(GameNameGenerator.java:78)

Comment: Yes, you should minimize the code which you want to ask instead of posting full code with so many problems

Comment: Sorry, still very new to this site and to programming

Comment: @MichaelDuffett: again as per my comment, start over, and don't ignore OOPs principles. You're ignoring first principles, something you can't do.